# override existing onkeydown function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, overriding, onkeydown

My extensions go through every input entered on an  on any website that is loaded.

What I do is I consider every onkeydown and manipulate it if it has some value.

my background js file contains the following:

```
document.onkeydown = returnKey; 

function returnKey(evt) {   
    var evt  = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);  
    if ( node.value == 'fi' ) { evt.srcElement.value = "??"; }  
}
```

My problem is when I have websites that already contains onkeydown function in their innerHTML webpage.

for instance:

taken from facebook's homepage:

```
<textarea class="uiTextareaAutogrow input" onkeydown="Bootloader.loadComponents([&quot;control-textarea&quot;], function() { TextAreaControl.getInstance(this) }.bind(this));
```

the switching of `node.value == 'fi'` in ?? is not executing since their `onkeydown="Bootloader`...runs before my `document.onkeydown`.

How do I cause my function to run before their onkeydown is executed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `document.onkeydown = returnKey;`, use

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', returnKey, true);
```

The most important part of this line is the third argument. When the value of this parameter is `true`, the event listener is triggered at capturing phase, which cannot be prevented using `event.preventDefault();` or `event.stopPropagation();`.