# Remove keydown event listener for anonymous vendor function

Tags: javascript

I'm incorporating SimpleMDE (https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) into my application and I would like to customize the behavior a bit by completely removing a keydown event listener that is bound to the escape key. I'd rather not alter the vendor javascript that I've imported, but the bound function is an anonymous function and I'm having a hard figuring out how to write the removeEventListener() in my own script.

From the vendor script:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event, 27 == e.keyCode && n.codemirror.getOption("fullScreen") && s(n)
}, !1);
```

Can anyone offer some thoughts as to how I might completely remove this event listener when the window loads?

Thank you!

Comment: Cant you use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @ShankarShastri - that's interesting, but it didn't work... maybe I've made a mistake?  Here's what I had: `document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode === 27){
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});`

Comment: Your code should override the existing code I think so..

Comment: It doesn't seem to be...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880126/override-existing-onkeydown-function

Comment: I ran it and added a `console.log(e)` and in the attributes for e it did say `defaultPrevented: true` but the behavior persisted...