# Chrome extension temporary disable event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a chrome extension which opens a dialog on `keydown` event. How can I disable all other `keydown` events while the dialog is open, end enable them after closing again (my `keydown` event listener is still enabled, so pressing Esc closes the dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't disable/enable them - you just *ignore* them if the value of the key event doesn't match "Escape" when the dialog is open.

Here "d" opens the dialog and "Escape" closes it. While the dialog is closed key values are added to a paragraph. While it's open they're not.

```js
const para = document.querySelector('p');
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

function handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (!dialog.open) {
    if (e.key === 'd') {
      dialog.show();
    } else {
      para.textContent = para.textContent + e.key;
    }
  } else {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
      dialog.close();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
<dialog>
  <p>My dialog. Escape to close</p>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Hi, dialog is part of chrome extension, so the dialog can be opened on any website thus I cannot modify event listeners add by website.

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880126/override-existing-onkeydown-function

Comment: But also note the documentation for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - it allows you to add/remove new listeners to a document rather than just replacing the existing ones.